# Header disappears when fixed position is added

Tags: html, css

I have a header below my hero section that adds the fixed method to the position property with js. When the position is set to fixed, the header disappears. The effect can be seen here :

http://redesign.hfe-observatories.org/about/.

I've tried the following solution:

[Header disappearing when position is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070793/header-disappearing-when-position-is-fixed)

But the header still disappears.

```
<section class="intro"></section> 
<div class="sticky-wrap">
  <header id="header"></header>
</div>
<section id="aim" class="features section-padding"></section>
```

```
.intro {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  height: 98%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(img/placeholder.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E9EA;
}

#header.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: try putting z-index to header and. top and left 0 value

Comment: Sorry, I am new to here.

Comment: Where's the relevant script then?